# If I derive $ e^{-2x} $, where does x go?

Tags: derivatives

So I have the function $$ e^{-2x} $$ and if I derive this I thought that I should get $$ -2xe^{-2x} $$ But the $x$ disappears, why? Is it an inner derivative and because of that, I also have to differentiate the expression $-2x$ when I put it in front of $e$? If that is the case, then $x$ would be 1 and -2 is the only character left.. Am I right?

Comment: $(-2x)'=-2$, no?

Comment: "differentiate (obtain derivative)", not "derive (prove)".

Comment: @theva Yes, what you say in your last paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your thoughts in the last paragraph.

We use the chain rule:

Let $u = -2x.\;$ Then $\;\dfrac {du}{dx} = -2.$

This gives us $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-2x}) = \frac d{dx}(e^u) = e^u\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right) = e^{-2x}(-2) = -2e^{-2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the basic definition of derivative. You have this:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-2x}\right) &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-2(x+h)}-e^{-2x}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-2x}(e^{-2h}-1)}{h}\\
&=e^{-2x}\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{-2h}-1}{h}
\end{align}
As you can see, there is no $x$ outside of the $e^{-2x}$. And you will find that the remaining limit is equal to $-2$.